# Creating modal in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal, simplemodal

I have a website running on Bootstrap, JQuery, HTML, CSS.
I want to add a modal output on my website such that when a user clicks on a hyperlink a modal opens and prints content of a txt file.
E.g. I have two text files which contains different details. And my website consists of sentence --> This is [sam](http://#). This is his [website](http://#). I want that when a user clicks on sam or website the respective text file is opened in a simple modal.

Comment: link tou attached don't work... and show your code please

Comment: I have added the link for example.

Comment: @לבנימלכה Currently I have just added <a href> tag which opens the text file in a new tab. But I want to open the text file in a modal. So is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: use bootstrap model:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: @לבנימלכה Its a good guide but it explains how to add a modal on a button. I want to add modal on a hyperlink

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/19aqgmLy/ that what you mean?

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes this is what I wanted

Comment: @לבנימלכה is there any way I could output the content of text file instead of modal body...? E.g. to view http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt in the modal?

Comment: see my edit in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bootstrap-modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) and instead use `button` use `a`:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 
 
  <a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal from a
  </a>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Edit to you comment

> is there any way I could output the content of text file in that
>   modal? E.g. to view http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt in the modal?
>   Use:

```
$.get( "http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt", function( data ) {
  $('.modal-body').html= data;
});
```

Or with `.ajax`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt", success: function(result){
            $('.modal-body').html(result);
        }});
});
```